# What is this "easy application of the Pythagorean theorem"?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I am reading Stillwell's *Elements of Algebra*, he gives this figure:

> $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

And then:

> [image]

What is this easy application of the Pythagorean theorem? I have tried to measure it with coordinates in the following way:

> $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

And then taking $d((0,0,\frac{T}{2}),({\frac{1}{2}},\frac{T-1}{2},0))$ which gives me $1$ when I substitute $T$ for $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ as expected. But I suspect he wanted something quite simpler.

Comment: I don't see any reason to suspect that isn't exactly what he had in mind.

Comment: Perhaps this is it. But sometimes people who know euclidean geometry can do some miracles in area/length measurement, as I know almost nothing of euclidean geometry (with ruler/compass constructions), then I thought there could have something else. I added more tags to see if such could happen.

Comment: I guess the word "easy" here means something more like straightforward, unsurprising, direct, boring, rather than something you can do in your head.

Comment: Just using that $t^2=t+1$ you get $|AB|^2 = (t/2)^2 + (1/2)^2 + ((t-1)/2)^2 = (t^2+1+(t-1)^2)/4 = (2t^2-2t+2)/4 = (t^2-t+1)/2 = ((t+1)-t+1)/2 = 2/2 = 1$